# Dynamic instability of microtubule

Tags: biochemistry

Why is it said that , warmth facilitates assembly and cold facilitates disassembly of microtubule?
But till now what I  had learnt is that as temperature increases so the kinetic energy of molecules increases so does the order decreases. 
So what is the reason behind the above phenomenon?

Comment: I would look at chemistry. Look for heat dependent reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper "Phase diagram of microtubules" Fygenson, 1994. it's evident that with increasing temperature the length of the aggregates is growing. But it of course depends on other additional parameteres like concentration and I assume the type of the protein - alpha and beta-tubulin.
[image]

Comment: thanks for showing interest, but I want reason for that graph.

Comment: There can be many reasons: simple Brownian dynamics is the best explanation I think.